# If all matter expanded

Tags: density, matter, exotic-matter

I know this is impossible (?), but what would happen if the electron orbit swelled, the gluons extended, and quarks lost density in relation to the gluons, would that affect the universe as we know it?

Comment: Most questions of the flavor "what would physics predict if  physics were different" are unanswerable... either your modification requires you to specify additional constraints or is simply contradictory.  It might take someone's thesis to work out parts of it, and provably isn't going to be answered (correctly) off the cuff.

Comment: This is a "What if...?" type of question which is "off topic" according to the PSE site policy.

Comment: I can't delete this because of the answer, didn't know hypothetical situations were not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide below a rough guess of what might be influenced or influence it, and possible cosmological effects. It is by no means an answer you can take to the bank. But it is based on some of the relevant physics. I'm probably missing other relevant issues, and I hope others chime in, if only as an exercise in non-factual what ifs. It's pretty hypothetical and may be off topic for this site.

Gravitationally, if those particles kept their masses the fact that they rotated further away should still matter, because it will mean that their binding energies are less, and if so their total effective mass would be less.

For electrons it would make no difference, basically, because they contribute so little, bound or not. But for instance the mass of the proton is more than the masses of the three quarks it is made of, and includes those binding energies and energies of the gluons. So the question would be, would the resulting proton still have the same mass? Also for the neutron. If they are more lightly bound, and the proton was bigger then, it's mass would probably be less, the gluons would be less relativistic. Still, because so lightly bound they could be split, and we'd now have gluons and quarks around. Quarks are normally confined, maybe they would then not be. In fact, it may then be that protons and neutrons may not have been produced (they were when the quarks and gluons cooled down so they could merge; if that bound state was too loose, they would have had to cool down much more, and possibly never form as the universe expanded and they got further from each other to bind).

Thus probably there would not be any protons or neutrons, and thus no atoms, just a soup of quarks and gluons and electrons/neutrinos expanding away from each other. None of our stars would have formed. Possibly quark stars may have formed, but not clear, and they may not be stable. And no rocks or planets with water or oxygen or people or any such thing.

An expanding universe would still exist, just the universe may not have many interesting things in it.

This is rough guess of some of the effects. The main effects would have to do with whether baryons (protons/neutrons) get formed, and then atoms, so that stars can form. Probably not. But a more accurate estimate might be given by others who are much more expert than me on baryogenesis, and how the QCD force could have been different to have bigger baryons, and thus whether they would be stable or not. Then at what temperature would that happen,  if too cold then there would not be enough of them to form stars and so on.